# Powershell script for count files and folders and send email

Tags: powershell, count, smtp, output

I found one script to calculate the number of files in a folder(looks Ok), but for some reason it doesn't work. The goal is that if the number of files in the folder exceeds five, I get an automatic notification about it.
If anyone can help me, I'm not very good at scripts, this is script that I found and doesn't work:

```
$Output = "c:\Test\*"

If (Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt10})
{
    $MailArgs = @{
            'To'          = "my@mail.com"
            'From'        = "some@mail.com"
            'Subject'     = "some text"
            'Body'        = "Number of files"
            'SmtpServer' = "smtp"
    }

    Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
    
}
```

Comment: You should be able to replace `(Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt10})` with `((Get-ChildItem $Output | Measure-Object).Count -gt 10)`.

Comment: Thank you Bill_Stewart, your code work great. Just one more question, if I want to check count of files in three subfolders. Is it possible to do some modification within this script? Thank you again.

Comment: Have a look at the `-Recurse` switch on `Get-ChildItem`, but also the `-File` switch, otherwise the cmdlet also lists subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
(Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 10})
```

with this:

```
((Get-ChildItem $Output | Measure-Object).Count -gt 10)
```